# Error in installing zooInspector

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

I am new to Zookeeper and I had installed zookeeper 3.4.6. When I tried to install zooInspector I got the following error

```
zooInspector.sh:18 : zooInspector.sh: lib/zookeeper3.4.6.jar:lib/jToaster1.0.4.jar:lib: not found
```

what I done was, First I navigated to zookeeper folder using terminal and run command ant and then copied zookeeper-3.4.6.jar to the lib folder and edited zooInspector.sh by replacing zooinspector-3.3.0 jar with zooinspector-3.4.6.jar

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

from your zookeeper installation root directory run: ant
then navigate to /path/to/your/zookeeper/build/contrib/ZooInspector. make sure you copied zookeeper-3.4.6.jar in zooInspector lib directory. by default it won't be there.

now replace the content of zooInspector.sh with the following line:

java -cp zookeeper-3.4.6-ZooInspector.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:lib/jtoaster-1.0.4.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:lib org.apache.zookeeper.inspector.ZooInspector

now run it: ./zooInspector.sh